# how to find format string {key:format} in a string, in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Now I have a dict object, whose key is of this kind:

```
d ={}
d['fruit'] = 'apple'   # user input from a configuration file
d['availablefruit'] = 'orange'  # generated by the program
```

My wish is that the user can set `d['fruit']='{availablefruit:s}'` in order to make use of the program generated value `orange`, by a `nestget` function, i.e.:

```
d['fruit'] = '{availablefruit:s}' # from user input
print d.nestget('fruit', None)   # return orange is applicable
```

the reason for doing this is to achieve some 'auto-fill' feature, that is, user can either get a pre-designated value (e.g. `apple`) for 'fruit', or use the machine generated
value from key `availablefruit` without knowing what fruit is available by the time the function `nestget` is called.

Here is problem: is there a nice function `getformatstringkeys` such that it returns `availablefruit` which are embedded in the string `{availablefruit:s}`, so that I can perform the `format` method of the string?

```
def nestget(key, default):
    val = d.get(key, default)
    keys_in_val = getformatstringkeys(val)
    return val.format(**{k:d[k] for k in keys_in_val})
```

as I test, the following

```
'{a:f},{b:f},{c:f}'.format(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5)
```

gives `'1,2,3'`, so It should work if I pass the whole dict `d` to `format` use val.format(**d). But it could be much more expensive when the dict is much bigger.

==== edit ====

thank you user2357112 -- what you are saying is right. I didn't think this way. actually what `format` do is to search the keys mentioned there and call the `dict.get()` and replace when kwargs is feed. How bright I was to intent to perform an action on parameters in order to call a function, while the action is already implemented by the function itself....

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question, mostly because you've done a poor job of naming your variables.

Comment: Why do you want this in the form of a format string? What's wrong with just having the user-provided value be `'key2'`?

Comment: Why would it be more expensive when the dict is bigger? `str.format` doesn't need to read the whole dict. It just uses the parts mentioned in the format string.

Comment: Let me see if I can understand. You want auto-fill functionality such that if a user provides a string that contains a reference to some pre-defined value ('key2'), the pre-defined value should be substituted in the place of the reference to the pre-defined value automatically. Is that close?

Comment: Bepetersn -- sorry for the poor quality of the question, I have updated the variable name so that a better sense is made. Yes, I want exactly you are saying.

Comment: user2357112 -- The reason for doing this is that the value for `key2` or, `availablefruit` is unknown until the program is actully run.

Comment: user2357112 -- actually what you are saying is right. I didn't think this way. actually what `format` do is to search the keys mentioned there and call the dict.get() method when kwargs is feed. I was intented to perform an action on parameters which is already implemented by the function itself....

Comment: From contextual information provided in your comments, it seems you're trying to achieve a mechanism where any of a number of predefined terms, if present in a string provided by the user, will be substituted with values defined at runtime. If this is the case, I see no reason you can't simply use a plain old dictionary with the to-be-substituted terms as keys, and to which you can assign values obtained from whatever datasource or random generator you want at runtime.

Comment: Asad -- My thinking is that it does matters. Because if I can separate the user defined with machine generated, and perform this `nestget` wheneven I want to retrieve the value, I can be sure that I get the most updated value, considering that the values are updated occasionally, here and there around the code. Some action can be performed without the key, and some cannot, so I wish I can only generate the key when the latter actions are performed, instead of loading and generating all the keys no matter what action is going to be made

Comment: Asad -- Yes, I also feel that an old way of dict can do the job, and I admit that I haven't got a very clear idea about whether or not this is necessary. I will think harder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of the possible strings available for substitution at runtime, that's all you need. Assuming you have a dictionary mapping between the available keywords and their pre-defined values--call it `available_fruit`--the problem becomes easy:

```
available_fruit = {'fruit1':'orange', 'fruit2':'banana'}
def get_format_string_keys(val):
    results = []
    for k, v in available_fruit.iteritems():
        if k in val:
            results.append((k,v))
    return results
```

This gives us:

```
>>> test_string = 'fruit1 is my favorite fruit'
>>> results = get_format_string_keys(test_string)
>>> for r in results:
...    print r
...
('fruit1', 'orange')
```

Building on this, in your `nestget` function, you can then simply:

```
>>> for r in results:
...    test_string.replace(*r)
...
'orange is my favorite fruit'
```